# How to reshape array by using kotlin like Python numpy?

Tags: java, kotlin

I use tensorflow lite(kotlin android) and get output like this:`[1,256,256,1]`, kotlin type is `Array<Array<Array<FloatArray>>>`, this output is grey-scale map, now I want get output max and min and change it to `[256,256]`, type: `Array<FloatArray>`, when use python numpy, it easy, how to reshape array by using kotlin/java on android? `foreach` performance is poor.

Comment: What are the four dimensions of the original array, and how should they relate to the two you want?

Comment: How have you reached the conclusion that "foreach performance is poor"?